# Can ClearType be taught y-dir AA and reverse subpixel-order when turning the display?

Tags: windows-7, cleartype

Recently I bought a Dell Latitude XT2, a multitouch Tablet PC. It runs happily and fine on Windows 7 now (though lacking the Tablet buttons and the nice "Auto" mode of the tablet).

Anyway, when turning the display ClearType essentially stays at the same setting, which means horizontal RGB subpixel order. So text gets a little weird when turning by 90° since ClearType can't change anything in that case and it gets really ugly when turned by 180° because by then the subpixel order is BGR which makes a blurry mess out of text.

Turning off ClearType is one option, though one I'd rather avoid since text really looks much more pleasant to me (except when turned) [no flame wars please].

So is there any way the ClearType settings would be adjusted automagically when turning the display? At the very least that it switches to BGR subpixel order when turning by 180° which would cover the two landscape options at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ClearType Switch](http://cleartypeswitch.codeplex.com/). Set to run along with your display rotation.

Comment: Nice program. As for changing the direction of antialiasing you also have no idea, I presume?

Comment: You presume correctly. ;) I use ClearType Switch on my Fujitsu tablet and hadn't found anything else to complain about so far - so wouldn't know anything about changing AA direction.

Comment: I think for changing the direction you will want to just disable subpixel antialiasing as they will not be ordered appropriately (the subpixels will be lying horizontally... i highly doubt the implementation supports this mode)

Comment: This still only switches between RGB and BGR. Linux already has support for VBGR and VRGB for years, don't know why MS engineers hadn't adapted their cleartype renderer for vertical aligned pixels. Instead they revert to greyscale anti-aliasing for modern UI apps on win 8

Comment: Now all this tool needs is another tool running it when the mouse cursor switches between screens and repainting the whole screen it is on (of course with hiding the popup dialog).